# How do I calculate number of list of strings from listbox and multiply?

Tags: c#

I have written a code here. It loops through. I have used an `if` statement to check if Fizz has printed three times in the ListBox. If it has, I would like a simple calculation with multiplication of 3. Then, prints out the value in the TextBox.

So, Fizz prints three times it will multiply my 3 which equals 9. How do I convert the string in the Listbox to int so that it can calculate `3 x 3 = 9, if that's how it should be done.

```
string Output = "Fizz";

for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
{
    if (a == 3)
    {
        for (int b = 1; b <= 3; b++)
        {
            listBox4.Items.Add(Output);
            int multiplyBy = 3; 
            //int numVal = Int32.Parse("3");
            listBox4.Items.Count.ToString();  
        }

        textBox1.Text = listBox4.Items.Count.ToString();            
    }
}
```

Thanks if anyone can help me.

Comment: The only proper tag for this question is C#. Tags are not used for targeting a large audience.

Comment: By the way, it's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Since when is 3 x 3 = 15 ?

Comment: @msmolcic lol. I will amended it

Comment: @Person I'm not sure what you're asking and even less sure what you're trying to do, but check out my answer and tell me what you wish to do differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but I will give it a try based on what you wrote:

```
string output = "Fizz";

// Loop from 1 to 10 for no reason
for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
{
    // Add "Fizz" item to listbox 3 times if 'a' equals 3
    if (a == 3)
    {
        for (int b = 1; b <= 3; b++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(output);
        }

        // Multiply number of items in listBox with 3 for no reason and display it in textbox
        textBox1.Text = (listBox1.Items.Count * 3).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to know how do I count words from the lisbox. Then do a calculation and display in the textbox. I hope I have explained properly this time and thank you for your swift answer because that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use Int32.Parse or Convert.ToInt32

See MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

and MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx